# Linking MySQL DB on Web Host to Shopify DB on a different Web Host

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, shopify

I have a web site which is hosted by GoDaddy and has a MySQL DB for collecting data and registration information. As the site did not have a shopping cart, we used the Shopify API and web site to create one.

Now the issue is that for some of our work, we need to get data from both these databases and link them to provide the relevant data.

Has anyone done this and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To synchronize the data between both websites your should use the [Shopify API](http://docs.shopify.com/api). Shopify doesn't allow access to their database directly.